# CSR Not working for multiple fields

Tags: 2013, jslink, client-side-rendering

Hi I have requirement to give display form link to the title and making description short for document library view.

I have added below code using jslink. The title is rendering as per my requirement, but there is no change in description field.

What i am doing wrong in below code?

```
RegisterModuleInit('/SiteAssets/Titlelink.js', updateTitle);
updateTitle();

function updateTitle() {
    var priorityFiledContext  = {};
    priorityFiledContext.Templates = {};    
    priorityFiledContext.Templates.Fields = {
        "Title": {
            "View": priorityFiledTemplate
        },
        "Description": {
            "View": DescriptionFiledTemplate
            }           
    };

    SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(priorityFiledContext);
}

function priorityFiledTemplate(ctx) {
    var currentURL = window.location.href;
    var url = String.format('{0}&amp;ID={1}&amp;source={2}', ctx.displayFormUrl, ctx.CurrentItem.ID, currentURL);
    var ret =   "<a href='" + url + "'>" + ctx.CurrentItem.Title + "</a>";  
    return ret; 
}
function DescriptionFiledTemplate(ctx) {        
    return "Test"; 
}
```

Comment: In place of `DescriptionFiledTemplate` you place simple `Test` string to check if that is working or not?

Comment: Now its working, the issue was internal name was different for description field after using internal name it started working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My issue got resolved. Actually Internal name was different for description field. After using internal name my issue got solved.